# Does Swift work on top of Objective c?

Tags: ios, swift

I believe, Swift is a compile time language.
But Im not sure whether it works on top of Objective C or it's a stand alone language.
Can someone please explain this?

-shoan

Comment: What do  you mean by top of objective-c?

Comment: by on top of means, is it a wrapper on Objective C?

Answer (score 4):

It's a separate language, with its own compiler. It interoperates with Objective-C and can use all of the existing Objective-C libraries.

Comment: How fast is it as compare to Objective c?

Comment: @shoan: That you should find out for yourself since it depends strongly on workload. Apple claims a modest speed boost, but you have to compile with `-Ofast` (maximum optimization, some safety checks disabled) to obtain top speed (this negates certain useful language features so it's not recommended for development).

Comment: I believe Swift actually uses the same LLVM compiler as Objective-C, but it is a different language. It also shares the same runtime, which allows you to have both languages in your project running at the same time.